# list.files stop looking after searcing in the master folder and the first subfolder in R

Tags: r, regex

Hello I'm using RStudio 0.99.903 for Windows 64 bits. I am in the folder named "UCI HAR Dataset", if I list all the files in this folder and the subfolders using : `list.files(recursive = TRUE)`, all files are listed as below:
[full list of .txt files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NY5T.png)

However, I want to improve the code to list all .txt files except for "feature_info" and "README", that's what I used `list.files(recursive = TRUE, pattern = "[^\\<_info\\> | ^\\<README\\>].txt")`, it worked by removing the two files I don't want, however, it also exclude those under "/train" folder. Can anyone help to clarify why it stops looking at the second subfolder?

Thanks!

Comment: Because the pattern matches only 5 chars: `[^\\<_info\\> | ^\\<README\\>]` matches 1 char that is not equal to `<`, `_`, `i`, `n`, etc, `.` matches any char and `txt` matches `txt` literal char sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I restudied regex and found a not so perfect solution to this with negative lookahead: `files <<- grep("(?<!info)\\.txt", list.files(recursive = T), perl = T, value = T); files <<- grep("(?<!README)\\.txt", files, perl = T, value = T)` to extract the file list excluding the text files containing "info" or "README" strings in the file names. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Try using alternation - `files <<- grep("(?<!README|info)\\.txt", files, perl = T, value = T)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^\\<_info\\> | ^\\<README\\>]` matches 1 char that is not equal to `<`, `_`, `i`, `n`, `f`, `o`, `>`, space, `|`, `^`, `R`, `E`, `D`, `M`, `E`, as `[^...]` is a negated bracket expression matching all chars other than those defined in the brackets. Then, then a `.`  matches any char and `txt` matches a `txt` as a literal char sequence.

Since you cannot use PCRE regex with [`list.files`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html), you may get all the files from the specified directory first, and then filter it out with `grep` that supports PCRE regex with *lookarounds* that you need here:

```
>  files <- list.files("C:\\5")
> files
[1] "info.txt"      "README.txt"    "some-text.txt"
> files <<- grep("(?<!^README|^info)\\.txt$", files, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
> files
[1] "some-text.txt"
```

Note that

- `(?<!^README|^info)` - is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `README` or `info` at the start of the string, and if they are located immediately to the left of the current location (that is right before...)
- `\\.` - a single dot (the pattern is `\.` but we need to double backslashes in the string literals to denote a literal backslash)
- `txt` - a literal char sequence
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies my question very well!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).